# minikube docker: Error response from daemon: connection refused when running sample docker container in MAC

Tags: macos, docker, minikube

I've installed `docker` client and `minikube` in MAC using [this](https://dhwaneetbhatt.com/blog/run-docker-without-docker-desktop-on-macos) tutorial. Used commands are below:

```
brew install hyperkit

brew install minikube


# Install Docker CLI

brew install docker

brew install docker-compose


# Start minikube

minikube start


# Tell Docker CLI to talk to minikube's VM

eval $(minikube docker-env)


# Save IP to a hostname

echo "`minikube ip` docker.local" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null
```

Though while running `docker run hello-world`, below error pops:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.3:49107->192.168.64.1:53: read: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Is there a way to resolve it? I tried to follow [this](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/#docker-on-macos), but it's probably not related to the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a solution, but as a workaround you can use virtualbox or any other VM driver. I've used virtualbox:

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```